# How connect or use NDK and Nativescript vuejs

Tags: android, android-ndk, nativescript-vue, vue-native

I have a project where we want to access to a finger print scanner (external scanner). The drivers are written in c++ (NDK).

does Native script support access to Native Components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a several issues about that on NativeScript's repo on GitHub, all lead to [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/566) where the solution is to create an AAR file from the CPP file and load it from NativeScript.

I found also [a detailed guide](http://www.blog.bdauria.com/?p=981) about how to do it, here are the main steps summarized by the author:

> - Create an Android library using Android Studio
> - Import the native C++ library and wrap the code we want to export into a Java class, using JNI
> - Export the library to a aar file, and import it into a new NativeScript plugin
> - Import the plugin into a new NativeScript application